# Minimizing a density function within spherical constraints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, optimization

So if I were to have a 3-Dimensional density function what would be the best way to find the minimum value within in the sphere? This is being done in C# so I can't iterate a massive of number of times but the function is differentiable so if any of those values would help. Additionally the function is fairly smooth and shouldn´t experience large changes within a single unit sphere.

As of right now I am just taking the gradient at the center and assuming that one unit away on the gradient is the minimum. Obviously this doesn't always work and has just been a good guess. The inaccuracy is causing me issues now though so I need to find a better solution that sacrifices minimal computational time has a near perfect success rate.

Obviously asking for a lot here but maybe just get me started somewhere.

Comment: Why the downvote? This question seems pretty legit to me.

Answer (score 0):

At local minima $\nabla f$ is zero, and $\nabla f$ always points towards the direction of maximum change. So what you can do is flow along the negative gradient with an update procedure
$$x_n:=x_{n-1}-\eta \nabla f(x_n)$$
This procedure will, if the learning rate $\eta$ is small enough, make $x_n$ smaller than $x_{n-1}$ and possibly converge towards a local minimum. It is also possible that this procedure wants you to leave the sphere. If it does that, then it is possible that the minimum lies on the surface of the sphere and not in the interior.

You can parametrise the surface of sphere with two angles $$g:(\varphi,\theta)\to (\sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta),\cos(\varphi)\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$$
By doing the above optimsation procedure with $f\circ g$ you will find local minima of $f$ on the surface of the sphere.